# Matriz Bidimensional em C

Tags: c, matriz, programação-funcional

Tenho um cadastro de produtos em C.
Os produtos podem ter até 30 caracteres(colunas), mas podem ser infinitos em quantidade(linhas).

Na declaração de variáveis, usei:

> **char** produtos[][30];

porém ao compilar, retorna que o tamanho do array não pode ser vazio.
Então se eu coloco um número de linhas,

> **char** produtos[10][30];

estou pré-definindo estaticamente a quantidade de produtos.

Como deixar livre esse número para que a matriz se auto-incremente a medida que o usuário entre com os dados?

Comment: Me parece que você terá que usar uma lista dinâmica.

Comment: Pesquise por alocação dinâmica de memória, `malloc`.

Comment: Se puder saber o tamanho em algum momento pode fazer como a primeira duplicata, caso contrário tem que fazer como nas última, oque é preciso muito cuidado, é muito fácil fazer errado. É o assunto que mais perguntam em C aqui porque quase ninguém consegue fazer certo, ou seja, todos terão bastante dificuldade em seres programadores de verdade.

Comment: @Maniero sim, por isso é necessário buscar a maneira correta de se fazer, aliás NINGUÉM nasce sabendo ;)